# Tkinter's .after() and recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tkinter

To update a widget in time I use the `.after()` method, usually in the following form:

```
def update():
    do_something()
    <widget>.after(<delay>, update)
```

It is my understanding that the widget waits for a certain amount of time and then executes the `update()` function, at the end of which the widget waits once again before re-executing the function and so on.

This seems to me a lot like recursion. So, the question is: Does `.after()` actually work by means of recursion or not?

If it does, then there is a limit to the depth of recursion, but the following example should prove that such limit is never reached:

```
from tkinter import *

counter = 0

def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    lbl.config(text=counter)
    root.after(10, count)

root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root, text='0')
lbl.pack()
Button(root, text='Start count', command=count).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In my system the limit to the depth of recursion is 1000, but this example goes far beyond that value in a few seconds until I stop it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recursion means that the current instance of a function is placed on hold and a new instance is created and run. `after` works differently, and is not recursion.

You can think of the mainloop as an infinite loop that maintains a todo list. The list has functions and the time that they ought to be run. The mainloop constantly checks the todo list and if an item in the todo list is due to be run, then the mainloop removes the item from the list and runs it. When it's done, it goes back to looping and checking the list. The `after` method just adds a function to this todo list along with a time to run it.

Answer (score 5):

> It is my understanding that the widget waits for a certain amount of time and then executes the update() function, at the end of which the widget waits once again before re-executing the function and so on.

The highlighted section is false. `after` simply places the function on a queue. It doesn't re-execute anything. `mainloop` simply pops things off of the "after" queue and runs them once.

> So, the question is: Does .after() actually work by means of recursion or not?

No. `after` should have been named `add_job_to_queue`. It isn't recursion, it simply places a job on a queue.

> If it does, then there is a limit to the depth of recursion, but the following example should prove that such limit is never reached:

```
def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    lbl.config(text=counter)
    root.after(10, count)
```

The reason no limit is reached is, again, because it's not recursion. When you call `count` by clicking on a button, it does some work and then it adds one item to the "after" queue. The length of the queue is now one.

When the time comes, `mainloop` will pop that item off of the queue, making the queue have a length of zero. Then, your code adds itself to the queue, making the length one. When the time comes, `mainloop` will pop that item off the queue, making the queue have a length of zero. Then, ...

Answer (score 1):

There's no recursion at all in your example, since `count()` is not called from itself (you're just telling Tk that it needs to call your function after 10ms) but invoked by Tk's main loop ;).

Answer (score 1):

in my program

```
keyboard=tk.Tk()
def readsm_s():
   ...
   keyboard.after(30, readsm_s)
```

readsm_s() is recalled many time, after that there is a error 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

```
find python the default depth of recursion is limited. （ the default is 1000 ）
```

https://www.codestudyblog.com/cs2112pya/1208015041.html

Answer (score -1):

Took a look at the python source code, I don't think `.after` works recursively. I starts new threads using the `Tcl` library.

```
def after(self, ms, func=None, *args):
    """Call function once after given time.
    MS specifies the time in milliseconds. FUNC gives the
    function which shall be called. Additional parameters
    are given as parameters to the function call.  Return
    identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel."""
    if not func:
        # I'd rather use time.sleep(ms*0.001)
        self.tk.call('after', ms)
    else:
        def callit():
            try:
                func(*args)
            finally:
                try:
                    self.deletecommand(name)
                except TclError:
                    pass
        callit.__name__ = func.__name__
        name = self._register(callit)
        return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
```

Modules/_tkinter.c: Registers the function and calls it. The `Tk` class is builtin class also located in the same file. The API works by calling Tcl library functions.

The function bounded to `tk.call` is `Tkapp_Call`:

```
{"call",                   Tkapp_Call, METH_VARARGS},
```

The comments for this function explain that this just calls `Tcl` functions.

```
/* This is the main entry point for calling a Tcl command.
   It supports three cases, with regard to threading:
   1. Tcl is not threaded: Must have the Tcl lock, then can invoke command in
      the context of the calling thread.
   2. Tcl is threaded, caller of the command is in the interpreter thread:
      Execute the command in the calling thread. Since the Tcl lock will
      not be used, we can merge that with case 1.
   3. Tcl is threaded, caller is in a different thread: Must queue an event to
      the interpreter thread. Allocation of Tcl objects needs to occur in the
      interpreter thread, so we ship the PyObject* args to the target thread,
      and perform processing there. */
```

Additionally, the arguments are freed when this is called at the end of the function: `Tkapp_CallDeallocArgs(objv, objStore, objc);`, so if the arguments are recursively used, they would not have been freed after 1 call.

Comment: This is a false statement: _"I starts new threads using the Tcl library."_ It definitely does _not_ start a new thread. Tkinter is single-threaded.